# weka logistic regression classifier not wroking

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, weka

I have a text dataset of size 15MB and it has close to 27k of rows, J48 TREE and NAÏVE BAYES classifiers work just fine, but when using logistic classifier i keep getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1JAr.png)
I have tried reszing the heap size but it still not working, same thing goes to deep learning and random forest.
what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your data have nominal attributes with many values? If so, 2GB may not be enough.

Why? [Logistic](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.java#L742) applies the [NominalToBinary](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html) filter, which generates binary attributes from labels (absence or presence). That can generate a lot of additional attributes if you have many multi-valued nominal atttibutes.

Solution? Work with a sub-sample of your data or increase the heap size.